# Remove Git Commit which has been pushed but failed

Tags: git, github

I have 2 dirty commits which I need to get rid of. When I do a git status below is what I get:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    Finals/Analysis/.ipynb_checkpoints/Analysis 3-checkpoint.ipynb
        deleted:    Finals/Analysis/Analysis 1.ipynb
        deleted:    Finals/Analysis/Analysis 2.ipynb
        deleted:    Finals/Analysis/Analysis 3.ipynb
        deleted:    Finals/Analysis/Analysis3_Image/wordcloud.png
        deleted:    Finals/Analysis/Download API Data.ipynb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I have tried `git reset --hard origin/master` which goes on for half an hour and does nothing.

Please, can someone help??
I have a backup of my files and I am fine if i can clone to my GITHUB directory online as well.

Comment: "I have tried `git reset --hard origin/master` which goes on for half an hour ..." Unless your repository has millions of files, there's something seriously wrong with your system. A typical `git reset --hard` finishes by the time you push the Enter key.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rebase -i
```

and then deleting the commits worked for me.

Thank you for the replies! Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done a git push to send your changes to the server yet, you can just delete your local files and clone from the server again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already pushed it then my suggestion would be to try a force push (great name for it right?)

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Answer (score -1):

`git reset --hard HEAD~2` should do the trick.